# If $R$ is a Ring and $F$ is the family of subsets $A$ of $\Omega$ such that the either $A$ or $A^c$ in $R$ show that $F$ is a field

Tags: measure-theory, finite-fields

[image]

I am reading some of the solution of past exercises my teacher give us. What I don't understand about this solution is that in the second part he proves that if $A\in R \rightarrow A^c\in F \rightarrow (A^c)^c=A\in F$ but there is another possibility which he seems to forget to mention is since $A\in R \rightarrow(A^c\in F \,\text{or}\, A\in F) \rightarrow ((A^c)^c=A\in F \,\text{or}\, A^c\in F)$) Which means that not always that $A\in F \rightarrow A^c\in F$ or am I missing something here

Comment: Please do **not** use some scan as a question.  For many reasons this is bad (non-searchable, bad for accessibility, it's hardly readable at all). Just type the full question in TeX codes (aka MathJax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A \in F$ and in particular $A \in R$ (as a subcase) then $B:=A^c$ obeys $B^c \in F$ *because* $B^c = (A^c)^c = A \in R$ so $B$ satisfies the *definition* to be in $F$ (its complement is in $R$) so $A^c \in F$ as required. I don't see a problem.

In the subcase that $A \in F$ and $A^c \in R$ we immediately have that $B:= A^c \in R$ so $A^c = B \in F$ is clear straightaway.

Comment: what about the subcase $A^c\in R$?

Comment: @gbd see edit... it's more trivial even

Comment: So is this enough $
A\in F \Longrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
A\in R\rightarrow (A^c)^c\in R\rightarrow A^c\in F\\
      A^c\in R\rightarrow A^c\in F
\end{cases}
$ ?

Comment: @gbd yes, essentially.